# Particle System Baking Issue: Unexpected Hair Particles (or stretched lines)

Tags: animation, particles, hair, cache

I'm having issues with particles. I initially had only "emitter" particles (not hair particles), but somehow, when I bake, the hair particles (lines) appear and stay there even after baking. I'm not sure what caused this.

I didn't give them a long lifespan, so I'm not sure why they're there. Those lines don't disappear until I delete the bake. Each shape has an "emitter" on it. Even when the playhead is at 0, those hair-like lines are stretched out.

Do you have any suggestions how I can fix this?
If there are multiple particle systems, what is the best way to render the particle system? (I have tried both Bake and Bake All Dynamics).

[image: Cone shape has hair line particle stretched out when baked]
[image: After baked random hair particle]
[image: screenshot of all options]

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you have multiple particle systems active on that object at once. Even if you don't have it selected, having a second particle system besides the one you are making adjustments to will still allow it to be visible. If you'd like to get rid of it, you can do so by selecting the hair system you don't want and then clicking the minus button on the right to remove it. If you'd like to keep it, you can instead click the TV and Camera buttons just to the right of the minus to toggle visibility in both preview and render mode.

[image]