# Emitters (baked particles) not showing Camera render/animation (Invisible, not rendering)

Tags: rendering, particles, camera, hair

I baked particles in Blender, but they don't show up in renders when I select the "Emitter" option.

When I attempted to Render Image and Render Animation, I couldn't see the particles. Although they were baked, they appear as squares instead of circles (emitter).

I've made several attempts to delete the cache, but it hasn't resolved the issue.

Please let me know if there is any way to fix them!!

[image: Rendered video]
[image: Show Emitter selected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your particle render settings are set to Halo, which by default does not show up in renders, as its more of a placeholder. If you want to make your particles visible you need to change the render settings as shown below.

Before changing settings:

[image: View-port Before][image: Settings Before]

After changing settings:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I have a question about baking particles. I initially had only "emitter" particles (not hair particles), but somehow, when I bake, the hair particles (lines) appear and stay there even after baking. I'm not sure what caused this. Do you happen to know a way to fix it?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301783/particle-system-baking-issue-unexpected-hair-particles-or-stretched-lines